# Issue with DXA app and Content Service -- strange SQL calls

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.8

DXA app is intermittently able to retrieve content -- sometimes it works and sometimes the DXA app throws a 500 error with below exception.

> ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00904: "BINARYVARI0_"."NAMESPACE_ID":
>   invalid identifier ERROR ODataFunctionProcessorImpl - Unexpected
>   exception when executing a function.
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet

Comment: similar to this error message, https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18398/sqlgrammarexception-occurs-at-discovery-service-when-creating-ttm-website, but he mentioned re-install fixed this issue, not sure, just a reference, good to raise it to sdl support to see

Answer (score 1):

This may be a known issue and possibly an upgrade to DXA 2.0 should resolve this intermittent 500 error.

I would recommend getting in touch with the SDL support and get their opinion about it.

background:
In one of our project we were receiving quite intermittent 500 Error and it was because of older version of newtonsoft json dll in DXA - and recommendation was to either update the version of that specific dll or upgrade to DXA 2.0

Comment: It would highly surprise me if the mentioned DB error could be caused by the version of Newtonsoft JSON used by the Web App. Nevertheless, contacting SDL Support sounds like a good advice.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. The issue was happening due to some bad storage info in the cd_storage file of the content service. When updated it resolved the issue.

Comment: glad it is resolved!